# MSBuild is not generating a Packages folder

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I'm executing an MSBuild (MSBuild.exe) from Powershell - it's partially working, however it is not creating the "Packages" folder (I need the deploy.cmd). It is, however, creating the "dev" folder and populating it with a few files. Are there any known reasons why this wouldn't be working? My script is fairly simple:

```
$msbuild = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
$options = "/p:Configuration=dev /p:DeployTarget=Package /p:DeployIisAppPath=TestProj /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True"

# create the build command and invoke it 
# note that if you want to debug, remove the "/noconsolelogger" 
# from the $options string
$clean = $msbuild + " C:\project\CMS.csproj " + $options + " /t:Clean"
$build = $msbuild + " C:\project\CMS.csproj " + $options + " /t:Build"

Invoke-Expression $clean
Invoke-Expression $build
write-host $build
```